# Perform an if statement on every cell in a range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Suppose I have a simple sheet like

```
  || A | B | C | D | E | F | G
==============================
1 || 1 | 0 |   | ? | 1 | 0 | 1
```

I want to create a new row where each value is either `1` or `0`. The logic is if the cell is either blank or `?` then it should be `0`.

The closest I got was

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A1:G1="?", 0, A1:G1))
```

which gave me

```
  || A | B | C | D | E | F | G
==============================
1 || 1 | 0 |   | ? | 1 | 0 | 1
2 || 1 | 0 |   | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1
```

But as soon as I add an `OR` for checking blanks with

```
=ArrayFormula(if(or(A1:G1="?", isblank(A1:G1)), 0, A1:G1))
```

then I only get 1 cell:

```
  || A | B | C | D | E | F | G
==============================
1 || 1 | 0 |   | ? | 1 | 0 | 1
2 || 1 |   |   |   |   |   |
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Simply place the other condition in the `value_is_false` location

   ```
   =ArrayFormula(if(A1:G1="?", 0, IF(ISBLANK(A1:G1), 0, A1:G1)))
   ```
2. Use `+` to represent OR. This works because "true" values are evaluated to `1` and "false" values are evaluated to `0`. So, `0+0=false`,  `1+0=true`. For AND, you multiply...`0*0=false`, `1*0=false`, `1*1=true`.

   ```
   =ArrayFormula(if((A1:G1="?")+(ISBLANK(A1:G1)), 0, A1:G1))
   ```